# Can void pointers be used in variables for writing and accessing hardware registers memory mapped?

Tags: c, linux-device-driver, pci, network-driver

in r8169_main driver they have variable for registers as void pointer..

On this page

> The kernel normally uses virtual addresses. Any address returned by kmalloc(), vmalloc(), and similar interfaces is a virtual address and can be stored in a void *.

> The virtual memory system (TLB, page tables, etc.) translates virtual addresses to CPU physical addresses, which are stored as “phys_addr_t” or “resource_size_t”. The kernel manages device resources like registers as physical addresses<-[so its physical address for registers why rtl8169 driver used void * <-Q

so to handle with registers we use physical address can be `phys_addr_t` or  `resource_size_t`. But I am confused as to why in r8168 Ethernet driver they did like this

```
 void __iomem *mmio_addr;
```

with void pointer

```
  #define RTL_W8(tp, reg, val8) writeb((val8), tp->mmio_addr + (reg));
```

void pointer normally used in virtual address but registers are not Virtual address. so what might be the reason of using void pointer for registers

Or is it because void pointer can contain anything.

```
int i=100;
void *p=&i;
printf("%d ",*(int*)p);
return 0;
```

its re-usability. it can point any thing and substituted  for anything means I can use void pointer in place of physical address data type with register which needs resource_size_t or phys_addr_t

void __iomem *mmio_addr;

or is it because in memory mapped IO all registers are placed on Memory area that driver and device also has it.

Comment: Looking at that project at Github, it looks that the usual Linux open source slop filled with questionable code. `tp->mmio_addr + (reg)` isn't standard C and their rationale is probably to use gcc non-standard extensions just for the sake of it. So the answer is probably "because: bad code".

Comment: *can be stored in a `void *`*  Seems like they took that "can be" and read it as "must be".  Imagine what would have happened if they had read somewhere that pointer values could be stored in cuneiform writing...

Comment: @Lundin while _in general_ this driver code can be considered bad, you are not correct about binding to the gcc specifics. `__iomem` is exactly telling why it’s okay to do like this.

Comment: @AndrewHenle what is `cuneiform` writing

Comment: Your misunderstanding here (see my previous comment) about the address of the registers (it has nothing to do with quality of the code). But it’s he idea is that your system is running in protected mode on the CPUs with MMU hardware, look for `ioremap()` call.

Comment: @0andriy can u please translate what @AndrewHenle meant by his comment about `cuneiform writing`

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=cuneiform+writing&tbm=isch  Just because something **can be** stored in a certain format doesn't mean that's the best format.  In this case, `void *` is wrong - that's not what the object **is**.

Comment: its kernel. I dont think gcc is useful in it. can anyone please tell why gcc matters?

Comment: so should `mmio_addr` variable be phys_addr_t or resource_size_t? should I change it?

Comment: @0andriy How come? Pointer arithmetic on void pointers isn't valid C and I don't see what that has to do with this __iomem. Void pointer arithmetic is a gcc extension aka Linux slop without a rationale.

Comment: You don't have to use `void __iomem *`, you can use `someothertype __iomem *` if you want - even a struct pointer type. But you should use the `__iomem` tag for MMIO virtual addresses. There is a quirk/extension of the GCC compiler that allows pointer airthmetic on `void *` and has `sizeof(void) == 1`, but doesn't allow `void *` to be dereferenced. The Linux kernel assumes that is the case.

Comment: The Linux kernel uses virtual addresses to access hardware registers. The physical address region of the hardware registers is mapped to a virtual address region by `ioremap()`. In the r8169 driver, that is hidden behind the call to `pcim_iomap_regions()` and the virtual address is retrieved by `tp->mmio_addr = pcim_iomap_table(pdev)[region];`.

Comment: @0andriy Actually `__iomem` doesn't tell the compiler anything. It only tells the sparse checker something. :-) And Linux uses arithmetic on `void *` all over the place that has nothing to do with `__iomem`.

Comment: @Lundin The Linux kernel uses something resembling standard C called `gnu89`. :-) (It's right there in the Makefile: `-std=gnu89`.)

Comment: @IanAbbott you're saying that they use this GCC quirk to allow pointer arithmetic but disallow dereferencing at compile time? That's interesting!

Comment: `ioremap is a kernel function that allows to access hardware through a mechanism called I/O mapped memory. There are certain addresses in memory that are intercepted by motherboard between CPU and RAM and redirected to other hardware, like disks or keyboard`

Comment: @IanAbbott `ioremap is a kernel function that allows to access hardware through a mechanism called I/O mapped memory. There are certain addresses in memory that are intercepted by motherboard between CPU and RAM and redirected to other hardware, like disks or keyboard`

Comment: @IanAbbott you said `The Linux kernel uses virtual addresses to access hardware registers. The physical address region of the hardware registers is mapped to a virtual address region by ioremap(). In the r8169 driver, that is hidden behind the call to pcim_iomap_regions() and the virtual address is retrieved by` there are certain addresses that are intercepted by motherboard and redirected to keyboard and Network adaptor.

Comment: @IanAbbott So in memory there are regions which are Mmio area and in mother what that interception is?; . does this mean virtual address in Mmio area are intercepted by motherboard so all the addresses area in pcim_iomap_regions() are intercepted by motherboard. Please confirm

Comment: Hardware registers on a device have physical addresses in the CPU's physical memory address space. The CPU only reads and writes to virtual memory addresses. In order to access those hardware registers, the CPU needs to set up page table entries in the memory management unit (MMU) to map a region of virtual address space to a region of physical address space. The driver code calls `ioremap()` (or some variant of that) to allocate a region of virtual address space and map it to the hardware registers in physical address space.

Comment: @IanAbbott can u also please direct me a link to some smart nic driver in torvald linux source source on github. I like to see it how it works. Thanks